# Access class in EJB project from War project in EAR project?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am creating a project based on MDB's and classes supporting those MDB's. I also need to use a ServletContextListener to interact with the MDB universe (details below), meaning I need a WAR project.

Question: How can the ServletContextListener access a class in the EJB project?

Project organization (standard Eclipse EAR project):

EAR Project
  has some jars in it
EJB Project
  has some MDB's and lots of other classes used by MDB's
WAR Project
  has ServletContextListener.

Why am I doing this? I need to start a thread when the project starts. This thread needs access to a bunch of the classes also used by the MDB's.

NOTE: I understand that I could put these common classes into a jar in the EAR project. If there is a way to do this such that a single eclipse "Debug As"->"On Server" then that would constitute a good solution. Whatever solution is provided needs to support that debug on server, with step debugging into all classes.

NOTE 2: I can tell Eclipse that the WAR project is dependent on the EJB project, which removes the Eclipse error flags, but eclipse shows a warning that this dependency will not exist in the deployed project, meaning my classes accessed from the WAR will fail to instantiate at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

With "standard" deployment on a Java EE server (meaning: with the default class loader policy), WAR classes "can see" everything that's in the enclosing EAR, and the EAR classes take precedence.

> I can tell Eclipse that the WAR project is dependent on the EJB project

Aren't you doing it the other way around? It's the EAR project that needs to have your WAR project in the project's "Properties -> Deployment Assembly" section.

Another possibility that comes to mind is that maybe you're trying to deploy on a non-Java EE server, like Tomcat, which does not support EARs. This could be why Eclipse says that the dependency won't exist in the deployed project.

Comment: I read a web page that agreed with you - before I made the post. It is possible that, on Glassfish (my target), it works as you say. However, Eclipse shows an error. I created my project in Eclipse as follows: (1) Create EAR project. (2) Create EJB project as member of EAR. (3) Create WAR project as member of EAR. A class in the WAR project could not see a class in the EJB project - per Eclipse error flag. I solved the problem by creating a "Utility" (library) project as part of the same EAR, and moving all my classes to it except the MDB's and the ServletContextListener. This seems overkill.